# How to handle onClick state change when an outside click handler "blocks" it?

Tags: reactjs

**The context:**

I am using the following outside click handler: https://github.com/airbnb/react-outside-click-handler

I have a standard sidebar and a hamburger button which shows/hides the sidebar when clicked. When I wrap my sidebar component with the outside click handler as per the docs everything works fine as I click anywhere on the canvas and it hides my sidebar.

```
    //App.js
    <OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={this.hideSideBar}>
      <SideBar show={this.state.sideBarOpen}/>
    </OutsideClickHandler>
```

**The problem:**

For the `<OutsideClickHandler>` I pass a function as a prop that sets the states of my sidebar and hamburger to `false` so that whenever I click outside the  component it can only hide it. I have another function that my hamburger `onClick` event executes as per below code:

```
sideBarToggler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return { sideBarOpen: !prevState.sideBarOpen, hamburgerOpen: !prevState.hamburgerOpen }})
}
```

My hamburger opens the `<SideBar>` fine, but when I try to click on the hamburger again I can't close the `<SideBar>` because my hamburger is **outside** the `<OutsideClickHandler>`. As `sideBarToggler` is called upon hamburger click it changes the state but `onOutsideClick={this.hideSideBar}` is called as well and states get changed back instantly. How can I fix the abomination I have written?

**EDIT**

`hideSideBar` function:

```
hideSideBar = () => {
    this.setState({sideBarOpen: false, hamburgerOpen: false })
}
```

Comment: Can you post a CodeSandbox link or other demo?

Comment: Unable at the moment and there's quite a bit of code. I am basically being dumb and changing my state twice which makes the states bang against each other as I understand.